# Why is the pricing for Web and Worker Role Instances greater than Windows Virtual machines?

Tags: azure

I am looking to move an existing application to the cloud. Its a ASP.Net application talking to a sql server database.

As far as I can see, I have 2 choices:

Web and Worker Role Instances and Windows Virtual machines.

The price for Web and Worker Role Instances is greater than Windows Virtual machines - I am unsure why this is?

Why would I want to use Web and Worker Role Instances over a Windows virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

Virtual Machines is currently in *Preview*. As such, operating costs are discounted. See [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-3) for the Preview vs. GA (General Availability) pricing. You'll see that, during Preview, Virtual Machines run $0.08 / core / hour, vs. $0.115 / hour in GA. This explains the lower cost vs. Cloud Service web/worker roles (which are in GA and not in Preview).

As far as reasons for using Web/Worker over Virtual Machines, that has probably been answered elsewhere (but worthy of a separate question nevertheless).

Answer (score 0):

Web and Worker Roles come under the Platform as a Service (PaaS) umbrella whereas Azure Virtual Machines (Currently in Preview) offer an Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) solution. Web and Worker Roles provide a platform you can deploy your .NET application to, directly from your development environment. Web and Worker Roles automatically handle the provisioning of IIS, opening of endpoints and the load-balancing of your application across multiple instances.

Virtual Machines on the other hand provide a bare bones Server 2008 system you can configure to meet your requirements. A VM is preferable if you need to run custom  applications that aren't easily deployable within IIS. But effectively you can do what you want with a VM as you are paying for the infrastructure, the flip side of that is your dealing with all the configuration overhead that comes with managing infrastructure.

If you're running a web application I would use a Web Role, it may be more expensive than a VM but there's a great deal going on under the covers that abstract away many of the problems of developing, deploying, maintaining and scaling a web application. Also if you need a 'High Availability' solution with automated Fail over, a web-role with two instances comes with a 99.95% SLA.